# publish work under CC BY-NC

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I have been creating a rpg system for the past few years, and I wish to put it online for the world to see, use freely, propose modifications and create with it as an inspiration.

As I wish to later publish it commercially, with additional content on the side, I was looking on a way to license it in a freely but not to freely way.

The CC By-NC-SA seems like it fits what I'm trying to do, but I have a few questions.

- 1. As the person imposing the license, could I still at a later date publish that work commercially?
- 2. If yes, could I include the modifications that were proposed by others to that publication (with citation of the person's name and the way they helped, of course)
- 3. If I'm having a company publish that work for me, how would the license affect it?

I'm aware that this question has similar answers already, but what I found did not make things clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't withdraw the license ([clause 3](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/legalcode) says "perpetual"), but apart from that there are no restrictions on what you might do with your own work.
2. It depends on whether the proposed changes rise to the level of a separate or derivative work. If someone suggests "I think you should have orcs in this" then you have no problem. But if someone sends you an orc character class with text and tables to drop into the system, or a modified document file containing the same, then they have copyright in that work and you need a license.
3. That would be a commercial matter to discuss with a publisher. Most publishers will want a limited period of exclusive rights. If your game system is already floating around the net with a permissive license then you can't give them exclusive rights, and that is going to harm your negotiating position.

Comment: Ok, so is there an alternative, other than creating a new kind of license that accomodate the problems you pointed out...which is a bit too complex for my goal? 
Or should I simply keep the system to myself until I consider it ready to publish, then publish it? I may have kept too much of my video game way of making